# I want to serialize my object to a string, but I did get an error "System.OutOfMemoryException"

Tags: c#, .net

I want to serialize my object to a string, but I did get an error:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
       at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString()
       at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
   at TEG.USBSharing.Utility.FileUtility.ValidateReadByStreamReader(StreamReader streamReader)
```

This is my code:
(1) Serialization

```
public static string Serialization<T>(T obj)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    {
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
        serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return FileUtility.ValidateReadByStreamReader(reader);
    }
}
```

(2) ReadToEnd

```
public string ValidateReadByStreamReader(StreamReader streamReader)
{
    string m_Data = string.Empty;
    if (streamReader != null)
    {
        m_Data = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return m_Data;
}
```

(3) My object

```
DataPacKet m_DataPacKet = new DataPacKet() {
    Command = DataPacKet.COMMAND_SEND_FILE_TRANSFER_CONTENT,
    GuidId = m_Guid,
    Data = new DataPacKetContent()
    {
        Sequence = i,
        DataBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(m_SendingBuffer),
    },
    TransferType = dataPacketRequest.TransferType }; string m_MessageFileDataPacKet =
JsonUtility.Serialization<DataPacKet>(m_DataPacKet);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the object that you are trying to serialize?

Comment: You're reading an entire stream into memory which clearly is too big to fit. What is `ValidateReadByStreamReader` doing? It's certainly not validating anything. Perhaps you can architect your code to process the stream as it's being read, rather than all at once.

Comment: Agree with Rob, its all about the memory consumption

Comment: What's in your object ??

Comment: Why are you using both JsonUtility and DataContractSerializer serialization on the same object?

Comment: There's not enough details here to answer the question, you're going to need to elaborate on the object being serialized.  I would look for any circular references in the object.

Comment: Do not return a string. Strings is copied by value. That is, each string is passed from method to method consumes memory. Return the `MemorStream` or `StreamReader`. The object is copied by reference (only 32 or 64 bits). Further work with the data in the stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your system has enough memory to contain your object, you can try compiling for x64:

If you are using Visual Studio, you can go to the project's properties and set the Platform target to x64 under Build tab.

[image]